# Fixing NoClassDefFoundError in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I just moved from using Atom to write Java to using VSCode to be able to use external libraries. Specifically, I need to be able to read and write to .xlsx files. To do this I'm using Apache POI. I've added it to my Java project under "Referenced Libraries" and am storing it in a /lib folder in my project folder.

[image: See this here.]

After doing this, I was able to import the classes I needed without the editor showing anything wrong, but when I tried to run my code, a NoClassDefError is thrown when I try to use anything from the imported classes.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
        at QuestionSet.exportToKahoot(QuestionSet.java:100)
        at QuestionSet.main(QuestionSet.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

Comment: You're missing dependencies of Apache POI, in this case Apache commons-io (and likely others, as Apache POI has something like 6 dependencies, e.g. see the `lib` folder in its download). This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't manage dependencies yourself, but use a tool like Maven or Gradle, as they will pull in transitive dependencies.

Comment: I suggest using Maven or Gradle rather than manually adding JARs to any folders. Atom can also use external libraries, but would have the same errors, FWIW

Comment: Download `commons-codec.jar`, `poi-ooxml-schemas.jar`, `xmlbeans.jar` and `stax-api.jar` from [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) then add them to referenced libraries, rebuild the project, and see if it helps.